# Inputting tab in windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I'm attempting to be able to input a tab 'command' into a loaded webpage in Firefox, using tab to move between points in the page. So far anything I've tried just doesn't work or errors out.

I'm only using basic windows cmd and .bat scripting.

Comment: A batch file cannot interface with a graphical user interface program.

Comment: set /p site= "Enter a website: "
    start firefox http://www.virustotal.com#url

Comment: yes, batch can _start_ any program, but it can not _interact_ with it's GUI.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Powershell if available.

Comment: @user5534161 ould probably use Vbscript or Jscript with sendkeys. But I would look at using AutoHotKey or AutoIt